# How to call Fast api file upload route

Tags: python, pandas, file-upload, function-call, fastapi

I have written fast API to upload a file but in my new requirement, I have to create CLI to upload a file for that I am calling route function.

```
@app.post("/uploadfile/")
async def create_upload_file(file: Uploadfile =File(...));
      pd.DataFrame = pd.read_csv(file.file)
      return True
```

create_upload_file(file=UploadFile(input_file_path))

when i tried to read that file like :  claims: pd.DataFrame = pd.read_csv(file.file) i am getting following  error

No columns to parse from file

Comment: try this `pd.DataFrame = pd.read_csv(file.file, delim_whitespace=True)`

Comment: Tried did not worked

Comment: what does your CSV look like?

Comment: INSURANCE NAME,PATIENT NAME,INSURANCE ID, DATE OF BIRTH,CPT, DATE OF SERVICE
COMMERCIAL,lastname,firstname,123,06/10/1965,xyz,05/10/2020

Comment: Could it be that you are getting the error due to relative paths that differ between the server and your app? Also, are you running the app with docker or bare metal?

Comment: I create API server as a submodule

Comment: I guess you are missing the `await` as you are inside an `async` path operation. Here is what the docs say - `When you use the async methods, FastAPI runs the file methods in a threadpool and awaits for them.`

Answer (score 2):

you can read the csv as following:

```
from io import BytesIO
df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(file.file.read()))
```